# Workflow not starting

Tags: workflow, sharepoint-designer

I have created a workflow that starts on change of a item. This change is triggered by the submission of a Sharepoint form to a library.
The workflow is updating a Sharepoint list creating a autonumber that is used in a Sharepoint form.

The workflow initiates and works fine as long as I, the creator of the workflow in SPD 2007, is logged on.

Any body else the workflow does not start, other logins have the same permissions as me, ie site owner.

Comment: First of all, check your ULS logs. There must be the exception message.

Comment: I am a end user modifying a subsite so I do not have access to the ULS logs

Answer (score 1):

Submitting a form to a library would be an on creation activity not an on change activity.  Are you testing this workflow by modifying an item whereas everyone else is submitting items?